# How do I extend the width of the header to the whole screen?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, width

**Problem:**

There is a white border around the header. How do I extend the header to the edge of the browser?

**What I've tried:**

I've tried adding `width={1}` to the `makeStyles` and into the `<Box>` component. Neither fixed the issue. Interestingly, the AppBar extends to the ends of the browser.

Any thoughts on how to extend the header and remove the white border that's around the header? I added an image below for clarity. Thank you.

[Code base](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-liskov-tkhtm?file=/src/components/Header.js)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a margin of 8px around the body.
[image]
Remove that margin and it would solve the issue.

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-wave-4t9vn

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  /*optional css below*/
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I see. None of the margins are coded through CSS style sheets. I'm having a hard time locating where the `margin: 8px` is. That's interesting because I didn't add that margin originally. Do you have any thoughts and where I might be able to locate that margin setting? Thank you.

Comment: @peyo: Added a working demo. Check it. Basically create a new CSS file and import it in index.js

Comment: @K K: Thank you! I created a new CSS file and imported it to index.js. It's working now.